# Найти ошибку в запросе на вставку

Tags: delphi, запрос-в-запросе

Собственно, запрос вида

```
DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Таблица2 (IDзаказ) VALUES (SELECT max(ID) FROM Таблица1)');
```

Хотелось объединить 2 запроса в одном. По отдельности они работают нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ключевое слово `VALUES` не нужно.

То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, это входящий в стандарт SQL запрос "`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`". Оформляется соответственно так:

```
INSERT INTO Таблица2 (IDзаказ) SELECT max(ID) FROM Таблица1
```

Comment: Пишу значит результат. При двойных скобках, как при варианте от DSKalugin выдаёт "Неопознаная ошибка", а вот вариант от Nofate отлично заработал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Какая СУБД? И какой текст ошибки? Не все СУБД поддерживают вложенные запросы.
Чаще всего их берут в скобки

```
DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Таблица2 (IDзаказ) VALUES ((SELECT max(ID) FROM Таблица1))');
```